# How to convert null rows to 0 and sum the entire column using DB2?

Tags: db2

I'm using the following query to sum the entire column. In the `TOREMOVEALLPRIV` column, I have both integer and `null` values.

I want to sum both `null` and integer values and print the total sum value.

Here is my query which print the sum values as `null`:

```
select 
    sum(URT.PRODSYS) as URT_SUM_PRODSYS,
    sum(URT.Users) as URT_SUM_USERS,
    sum(URT.total_orphaned) as URT_SUM_TOTAL_ORPHANED,
    sum(URT.Bp_errors) as URT_SUM_BP_ERRORS,
    sum(URT.Ma_errors) as URT_SUM_MA_ERRORS,
    sum(URT.Pp_errors) as URT_SUM_PP_ERRORS,
    sum(URT.REQUIREURTCBN) as URT_SUM_CBNREQ,
    sum(URT.REQUIREURTQEV) as URT_SUM_QEVREQ,
    sum(URT.REQUIREURTPRIV) as URT_SUM_PRIVREQ,
    sum(URT.cbnperf) as URT_SUM_CBNPERF,
    sum(URT.qevperf) as URT_SUM_QEVPERF,
    sum(URT.privperf) as URT_SUM_PRIVPERF,
    sum(URT.TO_REMOVEALLPRIV) as TO_REMOVEALLPRIV_SUM
  from
    URTCUSTSTATUS URT
    inner join CUSTOMER C on URT.customer_id=C.customer_id;
```

Output image:

[image: Column image]

Expected Output:

Instead of `null`, I need to print sum of rows whichever have integers.

Answer (score 4):

The `SUM` function automatically handles that for you. You said the column had a mix of `NULL` and numbers; the `SUM` automatically ignores the `NULL` values and correctly returns the sum of the numbers. You can read it on [IBM Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000765.html):

> The function is applied to the set of values derived from the argument values by the elimination of null values.

Note: All aggregate functions ignore `NULL` values except the `COUNT` function. Example: if you have two records with values `5` and `NULL`, the `SUM` and `AVG` functions will both return `5`, but the `COUNT` function will return `2`.

However, it seems that you misunderstood why you're getting `NULL` as a result. It's not because the column contains `null` values, it's because there are no records selected. That's the only case when the `SUM` function returns `NULL`. If you want to return zero in this case, you can use the `COALESCE` or `IFNULL` function. Both are the same for this scenario:

```
COALESCE(sum(URT.TO_REMOVEALLPRIV), 0) as TO_REMOVEALLPRIV_SUM
```

or

```
IFNULL(sum(URT.TO_REMOVEALLPRIV), 0) as TO_REMOVEALLPRIV_SUM
```

I'm guessing that you want to do the same to all other columns in your query, so I'm not sure why you only complained about the `TO_REMOVEALLPRIV` column.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the `COALESCE` function:

```
 select 
    sum(URT.PRODSYS) as URT_SUM_PRODSYS,
    sum(URT.Users) as URT_SUM_USERS,
    sum(URT.total_orphaned) as URT_SUM_TOTAL_ORPHANED,
    sum(URT.Bp_errors) as URT_SUM_BP_ERRORS,
    sum(URT.Ma_errors) as URT_SUM_MA_ERRORS,
    sum(URT.Pp_errors) as URT_SUM_PP_ERRORS,
    sum(URT.REQUIREURTCBN) as URT_SUM_CBNREQ,
    sum(URT.REQUIREURTQEV) as URT_SUM_QEVREQ,
    sum(URT.REQUIREURTPRIV) as URT_SUM_PRIVREQ,
    sum(URT.cbnperf) as URT_SUM_CBNPERF,
    sum(URT.qevperf) as URT_SUM_QEVPERF,
    sum(URT.privperf) as URT_SUM_PRIVPERF,
    sum(COALESCE(URT.TO_REMOVEALLPRIV,0)) as TO_REMOVEALLPRIV_SUM
  from
    URTCUSTSTATUS URT
    inner join CUSTOMER C on URT.customer_id=C.customer_id;
```

Comment: This code is a waste of resources. The `SUM` function ignores `NULL` values. Switch the order of the functions if you want the final result not to be `NULL`. Instead of checking each value, you only need to check the final result. See my answer for details.